# How to send a file as part of a request parameter in Postman

Tags: c#, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

this is my api endpoint

```
[HttpPost("stream")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadStreamAsync(FileUploadRequest request)
{
  // my code
}
```

this is the request model

```
FileUploadRequest
{ 
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public object Content { get; set; } //this can be either a json, a byte[] or a Stream
}
```

when i create a post request in Postman for testing a Stream content parameter, how do i send that file with my json request?

[this is my headers tab in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kesr.png)

[this is my request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w1f4.png)

when i send the request i get an error response:

```
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
"title": "Unsupported Media Type",
"status": 415,
"traceId": "00-bea9f28c0c2fd7e79ad8e296011e985a-177cdd0dcded6de1-00"
}
```

I've tried setting a form-body parameter of type file and upload it like that, and then set the other params i need in my request, each param in a different row.
i also tried to set one param as the file and one param as the json with the other params except for content (see img link above), also didn't work.

what am i doing wrong?

can this be done like this at all?

Comment: I think you can only use `IFormFile` to receive the file... `public IFormFile Content { get; set; }`

Comment: I've added this to my model in addition to what was there - 
public class FileUploadRequest
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FileType { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public object Content { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
still getting the same error. It doesn't even reach my breakpoint in vs. I'm probably missing a setting somewhere

Comment: I added details in my test, you may check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my model:

```
    public class FileUploadRequest
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        //public object Content { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Content { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my api:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("stream")]
    public string UploadStream(FileUploadRequest request)
    {
        return "asdf";
    }

}
```

Then when I call it :

[image]

With postman:

I set the body like this, and I didn't modify the headers.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I did exactly what you did (created a test request class with the 2 props you have here) and it still doesn't work.
still getting "Unsupported Media Type" :(

Comment: I'm not sure, in my test, I create a new asp.net core mvc project, and change the controller like above, and just now I installed postman to do the test and it worked as well.

Comment: I needed to add `[FromForm ]` to the endpoint for it to work.
I then added the rest of my props and it does work.
however, when i add the `public object Content { get; set; }` and change the other prop to `public IFormFile Stream { get; set; }` i get an error - 
`"errors": {
        "Content": [
            "The Content field is required."
        ]
    }`
i DO have a value in Content field in postman. it makes no sense...

Comment: ok, at least it seems that your issue is solved. Thank you for informing me about it.

Comment: I edited my latest comment, have a look

Comment: sorry I don't know, I know if you change Content to `string` instead of `object` will make it not null.

Comment: I needed to mark it nullable `public object? Content { get; set; }` and now it works. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method:

```
[STAThread]
public async Task UploadStreamAsync(FileUploadRequest FileUpload){
            using (HttpClient Request = new HttpClient())
                {
                    // If you need to add a header for Path or FileType: Request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HEADER, VALUE);

                    var Uri = new Uri(/*YOUR POST URL*/);
                    using (var Stream = File.OpenRead())
                    {
                        var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                        multipartContent.Add(
                            new StreamContent(Stream),
                            FileUploaded.FileName, // What the content is going to be named when uploaded
                            FileUploaded.Content /*Sets the value*/);

                        HttpRequestMessage Req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Uri);
                        Req.Content = multipartContent;
                        var Response = await Request.SendAsync(Req);
                        var Body = Response.Content; // Response
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: hi. thanks you for the reply,
however my problem isn't my method (i think..), it's my postman request. i've edited my question with more information on this including the error response i'm getting

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).